# It there a jest matcher that works like toEqual, but treats null and undefined as equal values?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have an API that does not omit JSON serialization for fields with "empty" (null, none, nil) values and returns all of them as `"fieldName": null`. I have typed DTOs in testing code (TypeScript), and I would like to make such fields as optional (?) and leave them undefined in many places. Unfortunately (for me) jest's toEqual() treats undefined (values in testing code) and null (values from API) as different values.
My current solution is to use union types like `string | null`, but it is pretty verbose, because I have to always initialize those fields.
I checked jest's reference and did not find an "off-the-shelf" solution. So, creation a custom matcher is the only way to solve my problem?
Note: I can't change policy of serialization in API.

Answer (score 4):

## `expect(null).toBe(undefined)` fails!

Basically what you have is that sometimes after evaluating an object you have `null` in one side and `undefined` in the other

I tried to use other jest methods as `toEqual` but symply didn't work.

#### My solution

`expect(null == undefined).toBe(true)`

Comment: It's ok but I don't like the usage of `==`, a better practice will be `expect(Boolean(result)).toBe(true)`

Comment: Use expect(null || undefined).toBeFalsy() - this is what jest recommends: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobefalsy

Comment: :face-palm: a `.toBeNullOrUndefined()` options seems obvious.`.toBeFalsy()` is too broad and seems dirty to me. Alternatively, `.toBeExactlyNull()` and `.toBeExactlyUndefined()` seems better, because in most cases we don't care if it's specifically `null` _or_ `undefined`, just that it's one or the other.

Comment: I had thought this was _precisely_ the difference between `toBe()` and `toEqual()` but this does not appear to work correctly for `null` equality checks against `undefined`.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You can create any matches that you want with Jest. For example this might be what you need exactly:

```js
beforeAll(function () {
  expect.extend({
    toBeMyEqual(received, expected) {
      const pass = this.equals(received, expected) ||
        (received === null && received === undefined) ||
        (received === undefined && received === null);
      if (pass) {
        return {
          message: () =>
            `expected ${received} not to equal ${expected}`,
          pass: true,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          message: () =>
            `expected ${received} to equal ${expected}`,
          pass: false,
        };
      }
    }
  })
})

test('should pass', () => {
  expect(null).toBeMyEqual(undefined);
})
```

You can probably add this to some setup script, I only added it in a beforeAll for testing's sake.

And here is the relevant documentation:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#custom-matchers-api

Answer (score 2):

after a long search, the best solution for this dilemma is to use
`.toBeTruthy`, in case value is `null` or `undefined`. details [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobetruthy)

However, keep in mind that it will fail with empty strings and with `false` booleans

Answer (score 2):

Using [jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended) ([an additional Jest matchers maintained by the Jest Community](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers)) you can use `toBeNil()`:

> Use `.toBeNil` when checking a value is `null` or `undefined`.
>
> ```js
> test('passes when value is null or undefined', () => {
>   expect(null).toBeNil()
>   expect(undefined).toBeNil()
>   expect(true).not.toBeNil()
> })
> ```

See: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tobenil

Answer (score 1):

Use `expect(null || undefined).toBeFalsy()` - this is what jest recommends: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobefalsy

Comment: `expect(myVar ?? undefined).;toBeUndefined()` would be better (TS), or for JS replace the `??` with `||` if you must.

Answer (score 0):

I use this util function for removing `null` and `undefined` fields of an object in my tests:

```js
const removeNonInitializedFields = e => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e, (key, value) => (value === null ? undefined : value)));

// Asserts
expect(removeNonInitializedFields(result))
  .toEqual(removeNonInitializedFields(expected));
```